# How to properly logout other users

Tags: jsf, jakarta-ee, jsf-2.2, logout, httpsession

In my web app I am trying to achieve the functionality, that an admin
is able to logout other currently logged in users.

What I have done so far:

- I created a POJO to store significant user information, including a referrence to the users HTTP session.
- This POJO is implementing `HttpSessionBindingListener`
- During the login process I put an instance of this POJO into the SessionMap. Via the `valueBound` method I am putting into a static Map, which stores all such logged-in-userinformation (on the unbound-Event I am removing it again
- In a seperated admin section I am now able to access the `HttpSession` of a specific user and invalidate it
- the logged-out user gets informed via websocket that he has been logged-out

Invalidating the `HttpSession` works fine and the mentioned `unbound` method is called. However, the problem is that if a in that way logged out user is still able to do AJAX requests. A new instance of hte ViewScoped Bean is created and assigned to the client and the request goes against this new instance.

What I would expect (or what I would like to achieve) is that sth like a ViewExpiredException is thrown instead and redirecting the user to the login page instead.
Or am I missing an important part in my concept?

Would it be enough to set up proper security-constraints in `web.xml` or would it just hide the conceptual problem?

(If it's important, the Bean is not a JSF Bean but a CDI ViewScoped bean.)

Application is running on Glassfish 4.1,, Mojarra 2.2.12

---

SessionBindingListener:

```
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@EqualsAndHashCode(of = {"user"})
public class UserSessionInfo implements HttpSessionBindingListener {

    @Getter private static final Map<UserSessionInfo, UserSessionInfo> sessions 
         = new HashMap<>(10);

    @Getter private final String user;
    @Getter private HttpSession session;

    @Override
    public void valueBound(HttpSessionBindingEvent event) {
        UserSessionInfo usi = sessions.remove(this);
        if (usi != null) {
            HttpSession hs = usi.session;
            if (hs != null) {
                hs.invalidate();
            }
        }
        this.session = event.getSession();
        sessions.put(this, this);
    }

    @Override
    public void valueUnbound(HttpSessionBindingEvent event) {
        sessions.remove(this);
    }

}
```

Login-method

```
public String login() {
        FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();        
        HttpServletRequest request = 
           (HttpServletRequest) context.getExternalContext().getRequest();
        try {
            request.login(username, password);
            context
                .getExternalContext()
                .getSessionMap().put(username, new UserSessionInfo(/* ...*/)));
            // ..
        } 
        // ....
        return "/index?faces-redirect=true";
    }
```

Admin-Method for logging out some other user:

```
public void logoff(UserSessionInfo usr) {
    EventBus eventBus = EventBusFactory.getDefault().eventBus();        
    eventBus.publish(CHANNEL, new DialogMessage(/*...*/));        
    usr.getSession().invalidate();           
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the session of your user is really invalidated, all requests should fail, ajax or not.

In one of my app, I have :

- security restrictions, through roles in web.xml
- session tracking with a HttpSessionListener and a Filter (the filter is the way I detect new sessions created by tomcat on login, to avoid session fixation)
- the possibility to "kill" another session, using session.invalidate

If a session is recreated "in your back", it must be because you have an unrestricted area being access. Require auth for all your all, with a rule such as :

```
<security-constraint>
    <display-name>Authenticated users</display-name>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>Authenticated users</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
        <http-method>GET</http-method>
        <http-method>POST</http-method>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
        <role-name>*</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
    <user-data-constraint>
        <transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>
    </user-data-constraint>
</security-constraint>
```

in web.xml, and it should be ok.